# Why is my featuredArticle not loading when using useEffect for data fetching?

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am clicking a link from the following component:

```
import React from "react";
import { FeaturedArticle } from "@/data/featureArticle";
import FeaturedArticleComponent from "./featured-article";
import Link from "next/link";

interface FeaturedArticlesContainerProps {
    articles: FeaturedArticle[];
}

const FeaturedArticlesContainer: React.FC<FeaturedArticlesContainerProps> = ({
    articles,
}) => {
    return (
        <section className="">
            <div className="grid grid-cols-1">
                {articles.map((article) => (
                    <Link key={article.title} href={`/feature/article/${article.urlSlug}`}>
                        <FeaturedArticleComponent article={article} />
                    </Link>
                ))}
            </div>

        </section>
    );
};

export default FeaturedArticlesContainer;
```

the folder structure for the pages that i want to open is in the following structure:

[image]

The feature pages has the following component:

```
"use client";

import { useParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getFeatureArticleBySlug, FeaturedArticleDetail } from '@/data/featureArticle';

export default function FeatureArticleDetail() {
  const { slug } = useParams() as { slug: string };
  const [featuredArticle, setFeaturedArticle] = useState<FeaturedArticleDetail | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        // Fetch featured articles from the graph request
        const featuredArticleData = await getFeatureArticleBySlug(slug);
        setFeaturedArticle(featuredArticleData);

        console.log("featuredArticle", featuredArticle);

      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data', error);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);



  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto p-4">
      {featuredArticle && (
        <article className="max-w-3xl mx-auto">
          <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold mb-4">{featuredArticle.title}</h1>
          <p className="text-gray-600 mb-4">{featuredArticle.createdAt}</p>
        </article>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

However this component is causing inconsistency in data, in the following screenshot of console.log. There is inconsistency in the data.

In the first `console.log` set from `getFeatureArticleBySlug` method, the data has been appropriately fetched from the graph request, however, `useEffect` has not set the `setFeaturedArticle`.

[image]

I am able to get the data and console from the following `graph-request`

```
export const getFeatureArticleBySlug = async (slug: string): Promise<FeaturedArticleDetail | null> => {
  const query = `
      query BlogBySlug($slug: String!) {
        featuredArticles(
          where: {urlSlug: $slug}
        ) {
          title
          createdAt
          keywords
          publishedBy {
            name
            picture
          }
          urlSlug
          image {
            url
          }
          description {
            html
          }
        }
      }
    `;

  const client = new GraphQLClient(endpoint);

  try {
    const data = await client.request<{ featuredArticles: FeaturedArticleDetail | null }>(
      query,
      {
        slug,
      }
    );
    console.log("query", data.featuredArticles)
    return data.featuredArticles || null; // Return null if blog is not found

  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Error fetching blog by slug: ${error}`);
  }
};
```

But the `featuredArticle` has been set as null most of the time, due to that the data are not being loaded on the dom.

I cannot find what might be causing this issue in my application.